# How to migrate all data of Quickbooks desktop into Salesforce

Tags: integration, quickbooks

I have created quickbooks desktop integration with Salesforce.

In this integration I have one question about insert all historic data of quickbooks desktop into Salesforce.

In quickbooks there are around for example 40,000 items and I want to insert all into Salesforce.

With reference of salesforce soap api call limits how can I achive this kind of functionality? Like I can add up to 200 records in a single create()
call.

Please advice me some options about how can I insert all the data into Salesforce.

Thank you

Comment: Not much sure but, if you can export the data from quickbooks you can import it in Salesforce using dataloader

Comment: Using dataloader can I map products with opportunity?

Comment: products are associated with Opportunity by OppotunityLineItem. Using external Ids you can map. It won't be straight forward.

Comment: Thaks Ashwani. I will try with dataloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration to salesforce is always challenging & you to keep few things in mind like,

1) Temporarily increase salesforce api calls by contacting salesforce support during migration
2) data space

Migration of Quickbooks Items, Customers, Transactions into salesforce can be handled 2 ways.

1) Using Integration tool like DBsync you can move all of these entities maintaining data integrity & proper use of quickbooks ID's.

2) Using Data Loader.